# Crawling and merging different sites

Tags: python, information-retrieval, web-crawler

I am crawling data from different sites and want to merge the data across sites. The format of the data differs across sites. Is there a generic way to do this, as in, not manually investigating and correcting it?

I am sure it can't be done in first attempt. Suppose I fix something manually, is there
a way to develop artificial intelligence into my code and it will handle for future cases?

```
+-----------------------------------------+
| 2.0MP                                   |
| NULL                                    |
| 5.0MP                                   |
| 8.0MP                                   |
| 1.3MP                                   |
| 3.2MP                                   |
| 5.0MP; 1.3MP front-facing               |
| 8.0MP; 1.3MP front-facing               |
| 3.0MP                                   |
| 2.0                                     |
| 2.0-8.0MP                               |
| 1.3                                     |
| 5.0MP (rear-facing)                     |
| 640 x 480 VGA                           |
| 5.1MP                                   |
| Yes                                     |
| 2.0 MP                                  |
| 3.2 MP                                  |
| 0.3MP                                   |
| 8.0MP; 1.3MP                            |
| 5.0MP; VGA front-facing                 |
| Up to 8.0MP                             |
| 5.0MP rear facing; 2.0MP front facing   |
| VGA                                     |
| 5.0                                     |
| 5.0MP rear; 1.3MP front                 |
| 0.6MP                                   |
| 8.0MP, VGA front-facing                 |
| Primary: 5.0MP; secondary: 1.3MP        |
| 1.3MP front, 8.0MP rear                 |
| 8.1MP                                   |
| 1680 x 480                              |
| 5.0 MP                                  |
| 5.0MP rear-facing; 1.3MP front-facing   |
| 3.0                                     |
| 5.0MP; VGA                              |
| 3.2MP: rear facing; 0.3MP: front facing |
| 3.1MP                                   |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: The data you've posted isn't very helpful. What does it represent? I'm guessing specs for phones. How should the data be organized? What process do you perform manually that you want done automatically?

Comment: Could you explain, what is in example?

Comment: You need to add some code .....

Comment: Please tell us what is the wanted output.